# recieve json data by ajax in client side

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying to receive JSON data (`listSize`, `MyList`) from the server by `Ajax` on the client side. I don't know if this is applicable or not. the ajax part is not working in my code.

here it is

```
function createList(startIndex,endIndex){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            var myVar = '<%=request.getAttribute("objKey")%>';
            var myObj = eval('(' + myVar + ')');
            myObj.listSize = endIndex;
            for (i = startIndex; i < myObj.listSize; i++) {
                $('body').append('<div id="div'+ i +'" />');
                $('#div' + i).append(myObj.MyList[i]);
            }
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "ServerSide.java", true);
    xhttp.send();   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say its not working are you getting an error or is the call not made to the server.
Check the URL is correct or not (clientSide.jsp is this your server url?)

Regards,
Nitin

Comment: i am not getting the expected output ..  i am not getting anything

Comment: i make updates please have a look

Comment: Nomally you will have URL such as xhttp.open("GET", "RetrievalServlet", true);
and on the server side you will have servlet with mapping mentioned in the URL
@WebServlet("/RetrievalServlet")
public class DBRetrievalServlet extends HttpServlet {
@Override
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
response.setContentType("application/json");
response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(jsondata)
}